# custom transform orientation doesn't align with object

Tags: transform-orientation

I'm following along a tutorial how to custom transform orientation. The cube which I select and apply the custom transform, doesn't follow the angle of the cube I want it to align with. Rather it resets to its initial position.

The correct result would be like the cube in Green and not the Red.

If anyone would like to see the 1 min tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHIZBoh3wdc

[image]

Comment: If you've rotated the cube in Edit mode, then its faces are not aligned with the Local orientation anymore and you need to find another method, is it the case?

Comment: I have not rotated the cube in Edit Mode. Are you getting the same results as the tutorial?  The only way I figured to get it aligned exactly the same was to apply all transformations on one cube, then link the object data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like since 2.9, the orientation that has been selected in the *Transform Orientations* dropdown menu won't be taken into account by default when you *Align to Transform Orientation*. Now you need to go into the *Operator* box and choose the *Orientation* you want. The previous way made more sense in my opinion (it may also be an oversight/bug).

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was it. I selected the Orientation in the Operator box, and it worked.  This tutorial was not made so long ago: 30 Jan 2020.  Maybe in the near future they'll fix it.

Comment: Agreed. It's an annoyance.. how do you report annoyances?

Comment: if it is a bug, Pablo explains here how to report: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4&feature=emb_logo ... but I'm not sure that it can be considered as a bug, it may be a choice? In that case the Right-Click Select website? https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ but I'm afraid no one will notice this request...